# how to save change and use json file

Tags: javascript, html

how to save change and use json file
Like a stack overflow, when you ask a question, even if you reload the page, the data is completed and if you go to local storage, you will not find it stored.

html

```
<button class="button" id="movetool10" onclick="movetool10()">change name & save</button>
```

javascript

```
var clickCounter10 = 0;
      var movetool10 = document.getElementById('movetool10')
      movetool10.onclick = function() {
        clickCounter10++;
        if (clickCounter10 ===2) {
          clickCounter10 = 0; // condition met, resset so it'll be met again
          document.getElementById('movetool10').innerHTML = 'hi';
          alert("hi user");
        } else {
          document.getElementById('movetool10').innerHTML = 'hello';
          alert("hello user")
        };
      };
```

Comment: Send it to backend and store it in a database. Please do basic research before asking, read [ask]

Comment: how to do it please send code or video

Comment: Imo that is out of scope for a Q&A. And this is not the place to ask for recommendations, please go to the help section and read what questions are on topic here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The code you have provided is client-side javascript. There is absolutely no way that you can save data permanently using plain javascript: because when a user refreshes it reloads.
2. If you want to learn how to save information permanently so that users can refresh the web page and the same information will still be there, then you need to watch a tutorial on how to go about databasing. I would recommend flask/python/dataset/sqlite3 for a beginner.
3. Stack overflow is a Q/A website, not an 'ask for someone to make a tutorial that has already been made 1000 times' website. You need to do prior research before coming here. Because, believe it or not, there are hundreds of already made, perfectly fine tutorials out there.

I'm writing this as an answer simply because I do not have enough characters in a comment.